# How to cast Class Data Source to JRDataSource

Tags: java, jasper-reports, spring-data-jpa

I have specific class like that:

```
public class testClass {

  private String name;

  private List<ListData> listDatas;

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public List<ListData> getListData() {
      return listData;
  }

  public void setListData(List<ListData> listData) {
      this.listData = listData;
  }
}
```

This class comes from `@RestController` side and `@RequestBody` sets all data with JSON. I also using JPA here.

On `@Service` layer I want to use `testClass` data, to `JasperFillManager`.

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, ???);
```

fillReport's 3. parameter expect `JRDataSource` type of data. But my object is not `JRDataSource`. How can I cast it to `JRDataSource`. İs there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *cast* the object as a `JRDataSource` because they aren't related to each other polymorphically. Instead you need write an *implementation* of `JRDataSource` that accesses your data. Something like this:

```
public class MyJRDataSource implements JRDataSource {
    private final testClass data;

    public MyJRDataSource(testClass data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    Object getFieldValue(JRField field) {
        // get value of field here
    }

    @Override
    boolean next() {
        // move to next row of data
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! If I answered your question please click the checkmark next to my answer so that others will know it's been answered :)

Answer (score 3):

Since `ListData` (`List<ListData>`) is a class of yours there is no need to re-invent the wheel, creating your own datasource. You could just use the [JRBeanCollectionDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html)

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,  params, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getListData()));
```

You will **automatically** get the fields in jrxml relative to the getters and setters in `ListData`